# Jolokia agent config using Spring

Tags: spring, java-8, javaagents, hawtio, jolokia

I am attempting to configure a Jolokia JVM agent in a Spring application by following the reference documentation for Jolokia Spring support given [here](https://jolokia.org/reference/html/jmx.html#jvm-spring).

I have added `jolokia-spring-1.3.1` as a maven dependency, and below is my spring application context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jolokia="http://www.jolokia.org/jolokia-spring/schema/config"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.jolokia.org/jolokia-spring/schema/config http://www.jolokia.org/jolokia-spring/schema/config/jolokia-config.xsd">
<jolokia:agent>
    <jolokia:config host="localhost" port="15151" debug="true" />
</jolokia:agent>
```

Running the code gives the following output on the console, however no Jolokia agent is created:

```
I> No access restrictor found, access to all MBean is allowed
I> Cannot join multicast group on NIF utun0: Can't assign requested address
I> Cannot join multicast group on NIF awdl0: Can't assign requested address
D> /192.168.1.247<-- Listening for queries
D> /192.168.1.247<-- Waiting
I> Cannot join multicast group on NIF utun0: Can't assign requested address
I> Cannot join multicast group on NIF awdl0: Can't assign requested address
D> /127.0.0.1<-- Listening for queries
D> /127.0.0.1<-- Waiting
```

Browsing to `http://127.0.0.1:15151/jolokia/` shows the following:

```json
{"request":{"type":"version"},"value":{"agent":"1.3.1","protocol":"7.2","config":{"maxDepth":"15","discoveryEnabled":"true","maxCollectionSize":"0","agentId":"192.168.1.247-3124-78dd667e-jvm","debug":"true","agentType":"jvm","historyMaxEntries":"10","agentContext":"\/jolokia","maxObjects":"0","debugMaxEntries":"100"},"info":{}},"timestamp":1434904598,"status":200}
```

Using [hawtio](http://hawt.io/) to list the available JVMs shows the JVM created, but is blank under 'Agent URL'.  Attempting to start an agent in hawtio gives the following error on the console:

```
I> jolokia:type=Config is already registered. Adding it with jolokia:type=Config,uuid=8bd5c6d9-cbf0-4569-b588-087f5c41522e, but you should revise your setup in order to either use a qualifier or ensure, that only a single agent gets registered (otherwise history functionality might not work)
```

If instead of using spring XML, I run the code with the following java option:

```
-javaagent:/Users/steve/jolokia-jvm-1.3.1-agent.jar=port=15000
```

Then the agent is correctly started and available, and this is confirmed by the following console output:

```
I> No access restrictor found, access to all MBean is allowed
I> Cannot join multicast group on NIF utun0: Can't assign requested address
I> Cannot join multicast group on NIF awdl0: Can't assign requested address
I> Cannot join multicast group on NIF utun0: Can't assign requested address
I> Cannot join multicast group on NIF awdl0: Can't assign requested address
Jolokia: Agent started with URL http://127.0.0.1:15000/jolokia/
```

As well as hawtio listing the agent and its correct port, 15000.

I have also tried re-writing the Spring config without using the Jolokia namespace as suggested in the reference documentation, for example:

```
<bean name="server" id="jolokia" class="org.jolokia.jvmagent.spring.SpringJolokiaAgent">
<property name="lookupConfig" value="false"/>
<property name="systemPropertiesMode" value="never"/>
<property name="config">
  <bean class="org.jolokia.jvmagent.spring.SpringJolokiaConfigHolder">
    <property name="config">
      <util:map>
        <entry key="autoStart" value="true"/>
        <entry key="host" value="0.0.0.0"/>
        <entry key="port" value="15151"/>
      </util:map>
    </property>
  </bean>
</property>
```

but this still gives the same problems.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong in the Spring config that is causing Jolokia agent to fail?

For information my Spring version is 4.1.6 and JDK is 1.8.0_45.

Thanks